# substitute a string space with newline in "r"

Tags: r, lapply, writetofile

I'm using R. I have an excel file which each rows of it consists of two or three lines description. I wish to write each rows in a separate text file. So, suppose I have a excel file with 100 rows, I will need 100 separate text files.

Is there any idea on how to do it in an efficient way?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is not a code-writing service. Please provide a reproducible example, including (a part of) your data, your expected output and what you've already tried. If you're unsure how to do that, here's [how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the file/ sheet as a csv and use `read.csv` to read in the csv as an R data frame.

You can then use `mapply` with the data frame variable (say it's called `x`, with a column `$desc` for the description).  Make a character vector with one entry for each row of your data frame called `fnms`.  Use `fnms <- paste0("text", 1:nrow(x), ".txt") or similar.

Put:

```
mapply(write, x$desc, fnms)
```